# addeventListner works only at the end of all iterations in a loop

Tags: javascript, event-listener

I am trying to make a game similar to guitar hero. I want the user to press the right key on the keyboard. Currently, all the required keys are highlighted first and then only the user can press those keys as the event listener works only after all the iterations of the loop. The keys appear all at once.

This is not I want. I want the keys to appear in regular intervals and the user should press the right key within a time limit.

So how do I make the evetListner run for each iteration of the loop?

```
var flag = 0;

//to generate  random key
    function getRandmFromSet(set) {
        var rndm = Math.floor(Math.random() * set.length);
        return set[rndm];
    }
    function actualGame(){
    var key_chosen = getRandmFromSet([65, 83, 68, 70, 71, 72, 74, 75, 76]);

    const key = document.querySelector(`.key[data-key="${key_chosen}"]`);
    console.log(key);
    key.classList.add("playingBeforePress");//animation

    window.addEventListener('keydown', function (e) {
        const audio = document.querySelector(`audio[data-key="${e.keyCode}"]`);
        const key_pressed = document.querySelector(`.key[data-key="${e.keyCode}"]`);
        const key = document.querySelector(`.key[data-key="${e.keyCode}"]`);

        if (e.keyCode == key_chosen) { //to check if the pey pressed is the right key
            console.log("correct key pressed");
            audio.currentTime = 0; 
            audio.play();
            key.classList.add("playingAfterPress");//animation
            setTimeout(function () {
                key_pressed.classList.remove("playingAfterPress");
            }, 100)

        }
        else {
            console.log("wrong key pressed");
            flag = 1
        }

    });
    };

    for(let i=0;i<5;++i){  //to generate 5 keys
        actualGame();
        }
```

Comment: The five identical event listeners that you’ve added are already running. Do you need to call the `setTimeout` callback after a `keydown` once every 100ms? Then you need to rethink your logic. Add a single event listener, not five of them.

Comment: There is only single event listener, i want to generate random number of keys multiple times , so I used a loop. The `setTimeout` is to change the animation if the user has pressed the right key. All  5 keys listeners are running but the problem is only after all the 5 keys are chosen, you can press the corresponding key. I want it in such a way that, once a key is highlighted, you have to press that key.

Comment: You shouldn't use five event listeners, they are all on the window and each gets fired with _every single_ keypress. With just one you can check yours key every turn. You need to remove the adding of event listeners from you actual game, so the event listener fires just once whenever a key is pressed.

Answer (score 0):

You should aproach this from a different angle, in essence you only need one event listener, the one to add to your `body` that will listen for keys. Then you want a list to check validity against, and then you want to display this feedback using an animation. I refactored your code to work consistently and simply:

```js
function listen( event ){
 
  let key = document.querySelector(`.key[data-key="${event.keyCode}"]`);
  let audio = document.querySelector( `audio[data-key="${event.keyCode}"]` );
 
  if( key && keys.indexOf( event.keyCode ) >= 0 ){
  
    console.log( 'right key pressed' );
  
    // Disabled since it wont work on Stack Overflow (CORS)
    // audio.currentTime = 0; 
    // audio.play();
  
    function ended(){
   
      key.classList.remove( 'right' );
      key.removeEventListener( 'animationend', ended );
   
    }
  
    key.addEventListener( 'animationend', ended );
    key.classList.add( 'right' );
  
  } else {
 
    console.log( 'wrong key pressed' );
  
    flag = 1;
  
    if( key ){
    
      function ended(){
   
        key.classList.remove( 'wrong' );
        key.removeEventListener( 'animationend', ended );
   
      }
  
      key.addEventListener( 'animationend', ended );
      key.classList.add( 'wrong' );
  
    }
    
  }
 
}


// A quick way to genersate the DOM required
function generateDOM( keys ){
  
  document.getElementById( 'keys' ).innerHTML = keys.reduce((html, key) => {
  
    html += `<div class="key" data-key="${key}">${key}</div><audio data-key="${key}"></audio>`;
    
    return html;
  
  }, '');
  
}

// Arrow Keys
var keys = [ 37, 38, 39, 40 ];

// Arrow Keys + Space + Enter
generateDOM( [].concat( keys, [ 32, 13 ] ) );

// Add a single listener for all keypress events
document.addEventListener( 'keydown', listen );
```

```css
@keyframes right {
  20% { background: green; }
}
@keyframes wrong {
  20% { background: red; }
}

.key {
  
  width: 80px;
  height: 80px;
  font-size: 20px;
  font-family: monospace;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  padding: 30px 0;
  text-align: center;
  background: lightgray;
  display: inline-block;
  
}

.wrong {

  animation: wrong 2s;
  
}
.right {

  animation: right 2s;
  
}
```

```html
<div id="keys"></div>
```

Then your randomiser could work like this:

```js
function listen( event ){
 
  let key = document.querySelector(`.key[data-key="${event.keyCode}"]`);
  let audio = document.querySelector( `audio[data-key="${event.keyCode}"]` );
 
  if( key && keys.indexOf( event.keyCode ) >= 0 ){
  
    console.log( 'right key pressed' );
  
    // Disabled since it wont work on Stack Overflow (CORS)
    // audio.currentTime = 0; 
    // audio.play();
  
    function ended(){
   
      key.classList.remove( 'right' );
      key.removeEventListener( 'animationend', ended );
      
      newkey();
   
    }
  
    key.addEventListener( 'animationend', ended );
    key.classList.add( 'right' );
  
  } else {
 
    console.log( 'wrong key pressed' );
  
    flag = 1;
  
    if( key ){
    
      function ended(){
   
        key.classList.remove( 'wrong' );
        key.removeEventListener( 'animationend', ended );
        
        newkey();
   
      }
  
      key.addEventListener( 'animationend', ended );
      key.classList.add( 'wrong' );
      
    }
    
  }
 
}


// A quick way to genersate the DOM required
function generateDOM( keys, selected ){
  
  document.getElementById( 'keys' ).innerHTML = keys.reduce((html, key) => {
  
    html += `<div class="key${selected === key ? ' selected' : ''}" data-key="${key}">${key}</div><audio data-key="${key}"></audio>`;
    
    return html;
  
  }, '');
  
}

var keys = [];

function newkey(){
  
  var all = [ 13, 32, 37, 38, 39, 30 ];
  var selected = keys[ 0 ] = all[ Math.floor( Math.random() * all.length ) ];
  
  generateDOM( all, selected );
  
}

newkey();

// Add a single listener for all keypress events
document.addEventListener( 'keydown', listen );
```

```css
@keyframes right {
  20% { background: green; }
}
@keyframes wrong {
  20% { background: red; }
}

.key {
  
  width: 80px;
  height: 80px;
  font-size: 20px;
  font-family: monospace;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  padding: 30px 0;
  text-align: center;
  background: lightgray;
  display: inline-block;
  
}

.selected {
  
  background: #ececec;
  
}
.wrong, .selected.wrong {

  animation: wrong 2s;
  
}
.right, .selected.right {

  animation: right 2s;
  
}
```

```html
<div id="keys"></div>
```